# Maximum consecutive subarray sum for a variable sliding window size

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, complexity

#### The Problem:

> Given an array of integers `L` find the largest sum of a consecutive subarray of size `k` or less.
>
> Constraints:
>
> - `2 <= len(L) <= 10000`
> - `3 <= k <= len(L)`
> - each element in the array will have an absolute value no more than `200`
> - there will be at least one positive integer in the array `L`
>
> Samples:
>
> `L=[-200, 91, 82, 43]`, `k=3`, the result should be `216`
>
> `L=[41, 90, -62, -16, 25, -61, -33, -32, -33]`, `k=5`, the result should be `131`

#### The Implementation:

Initially, I started with brute-forcing the problem, probing all sizes of the sliding window starting from `k` to `1`. This immediately got me into "time limit exceeded" situation.

The idea implemented below is based on picking out only positive integers initially. For every positive integer, we are looking if the following integers in a window are contributing to the current sum or not, cutting off situations when current sum drops below zero:

```
def maximum_consecutive_subarray(L, k):
    global_max = 0

    for index in range(len(L) - 1, -1, -1):
        if L[index] < 0:  # skipping all negative values
            continue

        sliding_index = index
        positive_count = positive_sum = 0

        while sliding_index >= 0 and positive_count < k:
            if L[sliding_index] >= 0:
                positive_count += 1
                positive_sum += L[sliding_index]

                global_max = max(global_max, positive_sum)
            else:
                negative_count = 1
                negative_sum = L[sliding_index]

                while sliding_index - 1 >= 0 > L[sliding_index - 1]:  # iterating over all consecutive negative values
                    negative_count += 1
                    negative_sum += L[sliding_index - 1]
                    sliding_index -= 1

                    if positive_count + negative_count == k:  # break if sliding window size limit reached
                        break

                if positive_sum + negative_sum > 0:  # if we still contribute to the maximum value
                    positive_count += negative_count
                    positive_sum += negative_sum
                else:
                    break  # exit this window if nothing was to contribute

            sliding_index -= 1

    return global_max
```

I would like to know if we can further improve the solution time complexity wise and would appreciate any other feedback.

Comment: Is this topic from a programming site (Hackerrank, etc.)? If so, could you provide a link?

Comment: @coderodde nope, unfortunately there is no way to test it out - I remember seeing similar problems somewhere on leetcode or hackerrank, but with a constant `k` - this is though, as it appears to be, a much simpler problem than the one where `k` is variable..thanks.

Comment: I did not realise one particular corner case. I added another loop in the code. Check it out.

Comment: Oh man. My implementation has a bug. I will try to fix it asap.

Comment: Your problem statement doesn't match the solution you noted, is the problem looking for the largest sum of positive integers only ? That's what your noted solutions would be.

Comment: @HaraldScheirich I agree that the problem description could be defined better, sorry for that. No, not only positive integers, e.g. in case of `L=[100, -1, 100, -20]` and `k=3`, the largest subarray sum would be `100 + (-1) + 100`. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I'm not one who really promotes pasting solutions, a lot of the answers seem to be answering in a way that a C programmer would answer the question. This is more a problem that you would want to solve in a pipeline in python due to that being how python does things fast and keeps a majority of the operations in C. Look into David Beasley's work if you want to minimize the amount of code you have to write by making everything into pipelines and checkout the `collections` library to get to know the tools that make things like windowed operations easy and a lot faster in python.

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import chain

def window(iterable,size):
    ''' yields wondows of a given size '''
    d = deque(maxlen=size)
    # normalize iterable into a generator
    iterable = (i for i in iterable)
    # fill d until it only needs one more
    for i in iterable:
        d.append(i)
        if len(d) == size-1:
            break
    # yield the windows
    for i in iterable:
        d.append(i)
        yield d

def max_sequential_subarray_sum(iterable, max_size):
    ''' returns the max sum of sequential slices of an iterable '''
    g = chain(*(window(iterable,i) for i in range(2,max_size+1)))
    return max(sum(i) for i in g if all(
        a<b for a,b in window(i,2)
    ) or all(
        a>b for a,b in window(i,2)
    ))


L=[-200, 91, 82, 43] 
k=3
print(max_sequential_subarray_sum(L,k))

L=[41, 90, -62, -16, 25, -61, -33, -32, -33]
k=5
print(max_sequential_subarray_sum(L,k))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an \$O(n)\$ solution for the problem. You can slightly modify the Kadane's algorithm and implement here. Firstly the problem statement shouldn't state "consecutive subarray", that's the wrong definition as subarray will have consecutive elements.

I won't give you the code, just the algorithm. So lets start. Let's take the sample 1 as example:

```
L=[-200, 91, 82, 43], k=3
```

- Firstly initialize two variables `max_till_here`, `max_so_far`, `count`, `max_so_far`  will store the answer, count will store window size.
- `start with idx = 0`, initially all variables are set to 0, now add `L[idx]` to max_till_here and check whether the value is negative , it is here so we will reset max_till_here to 0 and thats it.
- now `idx` becomes 1, `max_so_far` is still 0, again we add `L[idx]` to max_till_here and check if value is positive, since it is so we check if max_so_far is lesser than `max_till_here`, yes it is so `max_so_far` gets updated to 91, we also increment count as our current window size has become 1.
- now `idx` has become 2, we check if `count > k`, if it is then we subtract `a[idx-k]` from `max_till_here`
- now we add `L[idx]` to `max_till_here` and check for sign and repeat the same process, also remember if adding `L[idx]` makes value negative then we reset `count  = 0` and at each point we update our `max_so_far` if value is positive.
- we add `L[2]` to `max_till_here` and update max_so_far, then we add `L[3]` to `max_till_here` and update `max_so_far`. So, ultimately our `max_so_far` becomes 216 and voila!! here is your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> def maximum_consecutive_subarray(L, k):
> ```

- `consecutive` seems to be a bit redundant here.  Isn't a subarray consecutive by definition?
- You should add a docstring.  Without it, there's a lot about the function that is far from clear just by looking at its name and signature.  For example:

  - Is the subarray itself returned, a pair of `(start, stop)` indices, a starting index and length of extent, ... ?  Or is just the maximal *sum* returned.
  - What is `L`?  I would guess it's a list, and probably corresponds to the "array" from which the "subarray" is presumably picked.  This is the easy one, but should still be mentioned in the docstring.
  - What is `k`?  Is it the size of a sliding window?  If so, is it the *exact* size?  Is it the *minimum* allowable size?  The *maximum* allowable size?  Or is it something else?  Or maybe `k` is something completely different.  `k` might indicate some minimum or maximum value where, if the minimum is not met (or the maximum exceeded), `k` would be returned instead.

> ```
>     global_max = 0
> ```

I guess this is ok, since one of the constraints you gave is that there is at least one positive element.  However, you might want to add a comment to make it clear that this initialization is dependent on that constraint.  There are several reasons for this:

- It makes it clear why initialization to `0` is valid
- It serves as a reminder that this portion of the code might need to change if that constraint is changed or eliminated entirely.
- It serves as a reminder that we are making an assumption that could possibly be invalid in the future.  I.e., by explicitly stating the constraint, we provide for the possibility of re-verifying that constraint still holds as part of some future code review.

> ```
>     for index in range(len(L) - 1, -1, -1):
> ```

Why are you working back-to-front?  Why not work font-to-back?  Maybe there is a good reason, but it's not clear to me.

> ```
>         if L[index] < 0:  # skipping all negative values
>             continue
> ```

It's fairly obvious that you are skipping the negative values, even without the comment.  What more important, though, is why?  Shouldn't negative values be included in the sum?  If yes, then why are they being skipped?  If no, why not?  The rationale is much more important here than the tactic used.

> ```
>         sliding_index = index
> ```

It looks like you are keeping track of the other end of the subarray via `sliding_index`.  There's nothing wrong with that.  However, you could also use the current window size to derive `sliding_index` from `index`.

> ```
>         positive_count = positive_sum = 0
>
>         while sliding_index >= 0 and positive_count < k
>             if L[sliding_index] >= 0:
>                 positive_count += 1
>                 positive_sum += L[sliding_index]
>
>                 global_max = max(global_max, positive_sum)
>             else:
>                negative_count = 1
>                negative_sum = L[sliding_index]
>
>                while sliding_index - 1 >= 0 > L[sliding_index - 1]:  # iterating over all consecutive negative values
>                    negative_count += 1
>                    negative_sum += L[sliding_index - 1]
>                    sliding_index -= 1
>
>                    if positive_count + negative_count == k:  # break if sliding window size limit reached
>                        break
>
>                if positive_sum + negative_sum > 0:  # if we still contribute to the maximum value
>                    positive_count += negative_count
>                    positive_sum += negative_sum
>                else:
>                    break  # exit this window if nothing was to contribute
> ```

I'm not sure if this is a botched attempt at pre-mature optimization, but this can be simplified a lot.

- There's no need to treat negative elements any different from positive elements.
- Track the window size with *one* variable, not two.
- Keep the sum in *one* variable, not two.

You can replace this entire section of the code with something much simpler.  For example:

```
    window_sum = 0

    for sliding_index in L[index, max(0, index-k), -1]:
        window_sum += L[sliding_index]
        global_max = max(global_max, window_sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Maximum subarray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) is pretty well known problem with a simple algorithm to solve in `O(n)`. Directly from the link above:

```
def max_subarray(A):
    max_ending_here = max_so_far = A[0]
    for x in A[1:]:
        max_ending_here = max(x, max_ending_here + x)
        max_so_far = max(max_so_far, max_ending_here)
    return max_so_far
```

The problem mentions at least one positive integer, so this is equivalent to the above:

```
def max_subarray(A):
    max_ending_here = max_so_far = 0
    for x in A:
        max_ending_here = max(x, max_ending_here + x)
        max_so_far = max(max_so_far, max_ending_here)
    return max_so_far
```

This is pretty simple to extend to a maximum window size `k`:

```
def max_subarray(A, k):
    max_ending_here = max_so_far = window = 0
    for i, x in enumerate(A):
        if window == k:
            max_ending_here, window = max((last_x, 1), (max_ending_here-A[i-k], window-1))

        max_ending_here, window = max((x, 1), (max_ending_here+x, window+1))
        last_x, max_so_far = x, max(max_so_far, max_ending_here)
    return max_so_far
```

Example:

```
In []: max_subarray([41, 90, -62, -16, 25, -61, -33, -32, -33], 5)
Out[]: 131
In []: max_subarray([-200, 91, 82, 43], 3)
Out[]: 216
```